# using apply function with data.table, why this is so slow?

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I am using `data.table` package and I used this:

```
dt$date<- as.POSIXct(dt$date, tz="GMT")      (I know I can use fastPOSIXct)
2009-08-07 06:00:14
2009-08-07 06:00:15
2009-08-07 06:00:16 
2009-08-07 06:00:24
```

I want to change the time zone (there are many of them) and extract the hour. Suppose that I want to use apply function:

```
f <- function(x) {
  SydneyTime<-format(x["date"], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Australia/Sydney")
  Sy<-hour(SydneyTime)
  return(Sy)
}

mydata$SyHour <- apply(dt, 1, f)
```

This is too slow, am I missing something? I don't want to keep a copy of SydneyTime.

Thanks.

Comment: `apply` coerces the data.table to a matrix and you loose all the data.table magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to copy anything. `format.Date` is vectorised so you could use `:=` to make a new column in your `data.table` using the data from the original column. Here is a small reproducible example:

```
require( data.table )
#  Seconds in the day
n <- 86400

#  Make some data
DT <- data.table( Date = as.POSIXct( Sys.time()+seq(0,2*n,by=n) , tz = "GMT") )
#                  Date
#1: 2013-08-28 21:17:10
#2: 2013-08-29 21:17:10
#3: 2013-08-30 21:17:10

#  Change the TZ
DT[ , Date2:=format( Date , tz = "Australia/Sydney")]
#                  Date               Date2
#1: 2013-08-28 21:17:10 2013-08-29 06:17:10
#2: 2013-08-29 21:17:10 2013-08-30 06:17:10
#3: 2013-08-30 21:17:10 2013-08-31 06:17:10
```

#### EDit relating to comment below

`lapply` is designed to be used column-wise with a `data.table`. To modify the column `Date` in-place you can do this:

```
DT[ , lapply( .SD , format , tz = "Australia/Sydney" ) ]
```

But check the meaning of `.SD` and `.SDcols` before using this on your real data.

Comment: 1. I am assuming that the story behind SydneyTime<-..... and := are different and that's why they end up with different speed, is that right? 2. How do you implement this with apply family functions? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Yes. `:=` is a `data.table` function. Have a read about it by typing `?data.table::\`:=\``. 2. I don't understand why you *want* to use `apply` on a `data.table` when it isn't designed for it?